# Mixed effect model - Coefficient interpretation

Tags: mixed-model, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to fit a linear mixed effect model with random intercept using a predictor that ranges between 0 and 1. My response variable is the number of animal species in a plot and follows a negative binomial distribution (log link and zero-inflation). I'm using glmmADMB to build the model and I would like to report the coefficient obtained. The question is: since I used a predictor ranging from 0 to 1, is it correct to say that my coefficient represents the change that occurs in my target variable for 1 unit increase of the predictor? If this is correct, how can I estimate the change for 0.1 increase of the predictor?

Answer (score 1):

1) This is always true, regardless of the range of the predictor. Remember the log-link though.

2) Multiply your coefficient by 0.1.

Comment: Say I have a coefficient of 4.25, then basically if I wanted to know the change in my counts for each 0.01 increment in my predictor that would be: exp(4.25) * 0.01 = 0.701. If this holds, my counts should increase roughly of 1.5 for each 0.02 increase of my predictor. Is it correct?

Comment: @Giovanni No that would give a change of exp(4.25 * 0.01) = 1.043 on the count scale. An increment should always lead to an increase with a positive coefficient.

Comment: So if the predictor changes from 0.20 to 0.22 then the counts should increase of 2.086 (rounded to 2), right? But what about negative coefficients? If I had -4.25, would it mean a decrease of -1.043 for each 0.01 increase in the predictor?

Comment: @Giovanni No you do not understand the log-link. An increase of 0.02 means an increase of exp(4.25*0.02) = exp(4.25*0.01)^2 = 1.043^2 = 1.089 of the expected count.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now, but how can I deal with negative coefficients? Are they simply the inverse of the positive one or I have to make the exponential of the negative coefficients?